# Prevent website being displayed in WebView

Tags: android, ios, mobile, webview, mobile-browser

I have a site like `example.com` and I don't want it to be embedded in any mobile application. For example I don't want that pages in my domain to show the same content in WebView as when we navigate in desktop and mobile browsers (original content), instead I want a custom page when they are included in WebView (for ex. 'Page can be open only from normal browser')

Is this possible to be done?

P.S This is mainly for Android, but it will be great if it works for iOS.

**Edit:**
As I see that this question is not clear I want to add some more information.
I have a web site that is build with php (Codeigniter, but it doesn't really mater)
I don't have control over the application because someone else is trying to put my website in their Android application.

Comment: need clarity on your question

Comment: I have a website and someone embed it in their Android application without my permission. How can I prevent that without going to legal form? So is there anything that I can do with code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://example.com/"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.